# HTML5 Data-* attribute not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page with an HTML5 doctype and I'm trying to use the data attribute in my table's `<tr>` elements, like so:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($U)){
    if($c == "table-row-dark"){
        $c = "table-row-light";
    }else{
        $c = "table-row-dark";
    }
    echo "<tr data-id='".$res['rid']."' class='".$c."'>"
    ."<td>".$res['fname']." ".$res['lname']."</td>"
    ."<td>".$res['company']."</td>"
    ."<td>".$res['rcity'].", ".$res['rstate']."</td>"
    ."<td>".$res['rphone']."</td>"
    ."</tr>";
}
```

The following is my Javascript which adds an onclick listener to each row, then alerts the `data-id` attribute's value.

```
function addEvt(elem,eventType,handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
     }
    else if (elem.attachEvent){
        elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
    }
}

if(getElm('kickbacktbl')){
    var kbRows = getElm('kickbacktbl').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var kbrcount = kbRows.length;
    while(kbrcount--){
        if(kbRows[kbrcount]){
            var row = kbRows[kbrcount];
            addEvt(row,"click",function(e){
                cancelDefaultAction(e ? e:window.event);
                var did = row.getAttribute('data-id');
                var url = "kickback.php?id="+did;
                window.alert(url);
                //openShit(url);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when `url` is alerted , it shows the value of the attribute as `null`. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it while maintaining cross browser compatibility?

Comment: When you inspect the HTML, what do you see in the data-id attribute?

Comment: Also, if you're going to bother using double quotes for your PHP strings and singles for html, at least use variable interpolation!! `echo "<tr data-id='{$res['rid']}' class='{$c}'>";` etc.

Comment: @Jessica `<tr data-id='51105' class='table-row-light kick-back-row'>`

Comment: Perhaps try using javascript concatenation (`.concat()`) instead of + for the strings? I forget if you're allowed to actually use + on strings in JS?

Comment: What is the benefit of using interpolation as opposed to what I'm doing? The PHP works fine as is.

Comment: It's easier to read, and harder to mess up. What you have now is prone to errors and looks fugly.

Comment: lol, thanks for the tip. unfortunately `concat()` didn't work either.

Comment: In that case I suggest making a jsfiddle. I mostly work in jQuery so I use their data() functionality, so I'll have to bow out here.

Comment: can you `console.log(row)` and see what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `row.getAttribute('data-id');` to `this.getAttribute('data-id');`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your elements by tagname and then you try to use a jquery function for them.

```
this.getAttribute('data-id');
```

is the way to go.